# SAS / PROC FREQ TABLES - can I suppress frequencies and percents if frequency is less than a given value?

Tags: sas, excel-2010, suppress, ods

I'm using tagsets.excelxp in SAS to output dozens of two-way tables to an .xml file. Is there syntax that will suppress rows (frequencies and percents) if the frequency in that row is less than 10? I need to apply that in order to de-identify the results, and it would be ideal if I could automate the process rather than use conditional formatting in each of the outputted tables. Below is the syntax I'm using to create the tables.

ETA: I need those suppressed values to be included in the computation of column frequencies and percents, but I need them to be invisible in the final table (examples of options I have considered: gray out the entire row, turn the font white so it doesn't show for those cells, replace those values with an asterisk).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks!

dr j

```
%include 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\excltags.tpl';

ods tagsets.excelxp file = "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Participation_rdg_LSS_3-8.xml"
    style = MonoChromePrinter
    options(
    convert_percentages = 'yes'
    embedded_titles = 'yes'
    );
    title1 'Participation';
    title2 'LSS-Level';
    title3 'Grades 3-8';
    title4 'Reading';
    ods noproctitle;

proc sort data = part_rdg_3to8;
    by flag_accomm flag_participation lss_nm;
run;

proc freq data = part_rdg_3to8;
    by flag_accomm flag_participation;
        tables lss_nm*grade_p / crosslist nopercent;
run;

ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

Comment: Can you say why destination is tagsets.ExcelXP instead of Excel ?

Comment: Sure thing! I have 9.3, and ODS Excel is only available starting with 9.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D.Jay:  Proc FREQ does not contain any options for conditionally masking cells of it's output.  You can leverage the output data capture capability of the ODS system with a follow-up Proc REPORT to produce the desired masked output.

I am guessing on the roles of the `lss` and `grade_p` as to be a *skill level* and a *student grade level* respectively.

**Generate some sample data**

```
data have;
  do student_id = 1 to 10000;
    flag1 = ranuni(123) < 0.4;
    flag2 = ranuni(123) < 0.6;
    lss = byte(65+int(26*ranuni(123)));
    grade = int(6*ranuni(123));

    * at every third lss force data to have a low percent of grades < 3;
    if mod(rank(lss),3)=0 then
      do until (grade > 2 or _n_ < 0.15);
        grade = int(6*ranuni(123));
        _n_ = ranuni(123);
      end;
    else if mod(rank(lss),7)=0 then
      do until (grade < 3 or _n_ < 0.15);
        grade = int(6*ranuni(123));
        _n_ = ranuni(123);
      end;

    output;
  end;
run;

proc sort data=have;
  by flag1 flag2;
  *where lss in ('A' 'B') and flag1 and flag2; * remove comment to limit amount of output during 'learning the code' phase;
run;
```

**Perform the Proc FREQ**

Only capture the data corresponding to the output that would have been generated

```
ods _all_ close;
* ods trace on;
/* trace will log the Output names
 * that a procedure creates, and thus can be captured
 */
ods output CrossList=crosslist;

proc freq data=have;
  by flag1 flag2;
  tables lss * grade / crosslist nopercent;
run;

ods output close;
ods trace off;
```

**Now generate output to your target ODS destination (be it ExcelXP, html, pdf, etc)**

Reference output of which needs to be produced an equivalent having masked values.

```
* regular output of FREQ, to be compare to masked output
* of some information via REPORT;

proc freq data=have;
  by flag1 flag2;
  tables lss * grade / crosslist nopercent;
run;
```

Proc REPORT has great features for producing conditional output.  The compute block is used to select either a value or a masked value indicator for output.

```
options missing = ' ';

proc format;
  value $lss_report ' '= 'A0'x'Total';
  value grade_report . = 'Total';
  value blankfrq .b = '*masked*' ._=' ' other=[best8.];
  value blankpct .b = '*masked*' ._=' ' other=[6.2];

proc report data=CrossList;
  by flag1 flag2;
  columns
    ('Table of lss by grade'
    lss grade 
    Frequency RowPercent ColPercent
    FreqMask RowPMask ColPMask
    )
  ;
  define lss / order order=formatted format=$lss_report. missing;
  define grade / display format=grade_report.;
  define Frequency / display noprint;
  define RowPercent / display noprint;
  define ColPercent / display noprint;
  define FreqMask / computed format=blankfrq. 'Frequency' ;
  define RowPMask / computed format=blankpct. 'Row/Percent';
  define ColPMask / computed format=blankpct. 'Column/Percent';

  compute FreqMask;
    if 0 <= RowPercent < 10 
      then FreqMask = .b;
      else FreqMask = Frequency;
  endcomp;
  compute RowPMask;
    if 0 <= RowPercent < 10
      then RowPMask = .b;
      else RowPMask = RowPercent;
  endcomp;
  compute ColPMask;
    if 0 <= RowPercent < 10 
      then ColPMask = .b;
      else ColPMask = ColPercent;
  endcomp;
run;

ods html close;
```

If you have to produce lots of cross listings for different data sets, the code is easily macro-ized.

[image]

Comment: Looping back to thank you! I was in a crunch and then forgot to come back and express my appreciation. This worked famously, and I've since macro-ized it and used it when creating several thousand tables that would have otherwise been suppressed by hand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When I've done this in the past, I've first generated the frequency to a dataset, then filtered out the N, then re-printed the dataset (using tabulate usually).

If you can't recreate the frequency table perfectly from the freq output, you can do a simple frequency, check which IDs or variables or what have you to exclude, and then filter them out from the input dataset and rerun the whole frequency.

Comment: Thanks, @Joe! The catch is that I need those values to be counted in the computation of column frequencies and percents. I just need them to be invisible in the final table (examples of options I have considered: gray out the entire row, turn the font white so it doesn't show for those cells, replace those values with an asterisk). Hmmm...

Comment: @doctorjay For the most part that isn't a problem with my suggested solution.  You can simply do all those computations of marginals in the initial frequency, then filter out the undesired rows, then do a simpler tabulation (or `PROC REPORT` even) to output the data from there.  The only iffy bits come when you have very specific output needs that happen to match exactly the original format of `proc freq` or whatever and you can't get that from `proc report`.  Then you either roll your own summaries at much more difficulty, or you use customized weights which are very hard to do.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you! The only drawback I can see is that I'd still have to identify the undesired rows manually, which could take hours. But I'll definitely file this away for smaller sets of output - I do a lot of de-identification. Thanks so much!

Comment: Manually? I hope you'd have some way of doing it automatically, but if you don't then yes it would be messy.  You could even have Excel do the filtering out and removing, if that's easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can with PROC FREQ, but you can easily replicate your code with PROC TABULATE and you can use a custom format there to mask the numbers. This example sets it to M for missing and N for less than 5 and with one decimal place for the rest of the values. You could also replace the M/N with a space (single space) to have no values shown instead.

```
*Create a format to mask values less than 5;
proc format;
 value mask_fmt

. = 'M' /*missing*/
 low - < 5='N' /*less than 5 */
 other = [8.1]; /*remaining values with one decimal place*/
run;

*sort data for demo;
proc sort data=sashelp.cars out=cars;
 by origin;
run;

ods tagsets.excelxp file='/folders/myfolders/demo.xml';


*values partially masked;
proc tabulate data=cars;
 where origin='Asia';
 by origin;
 class make cylinders;
 table make, cylinders*n*f=mask_fmt. ;
run;

ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

This was tested on SAS UE.

EDIT: Forgot the percentage piece, so this likely will not work for that, primarily because I don't think you'll get the percentages the same as in PROC FREQ (appearance) so it depends on how important that is to you. The other possibility to accomplish this would be to modify the PROC FREQ template to use the custom format as above. Unfortunately I do not have time to mock this up for you but maybe someone else can. I'll leave this here to help get you started and delete it later on.

Comment: A very belated thank you! My apologies - I was in a rush and then forgot to come back and say thanks! Even though it didn't work for this application, it's great knowledge to have in my back pocket! Thanks!!!